# Migrate module showing 0 processed on production server

Tags: migrations

We intend to run regular migrates to update content and the initial migrate was on my local machine.  Now that its up on production I changed the connection strings to the database and its showing 0 processed.  This is the same database structure except one is local and the other is on production.

How can I get migrate module to recognize the production database with these nodes already processed?  I would just reimport them but the problem is that there are other nodes that reference these already and it will mess up a lot of structure.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I didn't take as much time to look into this and then had a light bulb moment.  Migrate actually creates a table in the database of the one it is importing from (probably skimmed over this in the docs).  So I need to do a sync of those tables from my local to production.